# SQL Server trigger that stops rows from being added to a table if one of the columns has a value that is not already in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server that has the following four columns:

```
ID_Number
Firstname
Lastname
Group
```

I am in need of a trigger that does not allow new rows to be added to this table, if the row that is being added contains a value that is not already present in the Group column of the table. Ideally, the trigger would also create an Error message (potentially using the `RAISERROR` command) that would highlight the fact that the row being added contains a value for the Group column that is not already present in the database.

I am new to T-SQL and any help with this problem will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like your describing a foreign key. Why not use one?

Comment: So you start with an empty table that doesn't allow _any_ inserts. Then what?

Answer (score 3):

You are doing this wrong.  You want a separate table for groups (and `group` is a bad name because it is a SQL reserve word).  I would recommend:

```
create table groups (
    group_id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    group_name varchar(255) not null unique
);

create table <whatever> (
    id_number int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    first_name varchar(255),
    last_name varchar(255),
    group_id int not null,  -- has to be defined
    constraint fk_group_id foreign key (group_id) references groups(group_id)
);
```

Voila!  Every row has to have a group.  And the group has to already be defined.  You need to insert valid group names before inserting into your table.  So:

```
insert into groups (group_name)
    values ('group anme')

insert into t (first_name, last_name, group_id)
    select @first_name, @last_name, group_id
    from groups g
    where g.group_name = @group_name;
```

EDIT:

You can also use `group_name` as the primary key:

```
create table groups (
    group_name varchar(255) not null primary key
);

create table <whatever> (
    id_number int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    first_name varchar(255),
    last_name varchar(255),
    group_name varchar(255) not null,  -- has to be defined
    constraint fk_group_id foreign key (group_id) references groups(group_id)
);
```

You still need to insert the `group_name` first into `groups` -- signifying that it is a valid value.  However, I am not a fan of using strings as primary keys because they are generally less efficient (primarily due to the extra space the take up with foreign key references).

Comment: This solution seems to work if the group_id is the value that is being manually inserted into the table. Could you advise how you recommend modifying the query so it works for the group_name being the inserted value instead of the group_id being inserted?

Thank you for this first answer, it has been useful.